# Como atualizar o estado do GRUD?

Tags: react

**Como faço para atualizar o estado ?**

Como faço para clicar em **cadastrar** e atualizar a tela na hora, e quando clicar no **X** ele deletar e também atualizar na hora a pagina. Não estou conseguindo, tenho que dar um atualizar na pagina manual.

Pessoal a API é um arquivo json e foi usado o **json-server** para simular. O exercício também precisa usar **TypeScript**.

***segue o código.***

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {

  const [usuarios, setUsuarios] = useState<any>([])

  const inputNome = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  const inputIdade = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  const inputEmpresa = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  const inputTelefone = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  const mostraUsuarios = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/usuarios")
      .then(resposta => setUsuarios(resposta.data))
  }

  const enviarCadastro = () => {

    const requisicao = {
      name: inputNome.current?.value,
      age: inputIdade.current?.value,
      company: inputEmpresa.current?.value,
      phone: inputTelefone.current?.value
    }

    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/usuarios", requisicao)
    mostraUsuarios()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    mostraUsuarios()
  }, [])

  const deletarUsuario = (id: any) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/usuarios/${id}`)
    mostraUsuarios()
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" ref={inputNome} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Idade" ref={inputIdade} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Empresa" ref={inputEmpresa} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Telefone" ref={inputTelefone} />
      <button onClick={enviarCadastro}>Cadastrar</button>

      <br/>

      <ul>
        
        { usuarios !== null && 
          usuarios.map((item: any) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.name}  <button onClick={() => deletarUsuario(item.id)}>X</button></li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: o axios no `enviarCadastro` está sendo executado ao mesmo tempo que o axios do `mostrarUsuarios` precisa primeiro um depois o outro deve ser esse o seu problema a atualização na bate com o cadatro feito?

Comment: Tudo bem Novic, então eu quero na hora que clicar em cadastro que ele mostre na tela já o nome , e quando clicar no X já delete o usuário da tela. Estou perdido como fazer isso, se você puder me ajudar, e obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar como atualizar o estado e já mostrar ele na tela ?. Do jeito que fiz só consigo se for no botão do Google manual.

Comment: `axios.post("http://localhost:4000/usuarios"` isso retornar alguma coisa do back end?

Comment: Tudo bem Novic. Então esse post esta adicionando na API, vamos supor vc digita um nome e quando clica em cadastrar ele adiciona na API, porem eu preciso que ele mostre na tela tb, só que não consigo. Do jeito que esta no código ai eu preciso dar um recarregar pagina no Google para aparecer.

Comment: nessa linha `axios.post("http://localhost:4000/usuarios", requisicao)` coloque `axios.post("http://localhost:4000/usuarios", requisicao).then(() => {mostraUsuarios()})` e remova da ultima linha `mostraUsuarios()`

Comment: Eu tentei aqui Novic, mas não deu certo tb.

Comment: o que acontece na realidade, o que dá de erros? já olhou o console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu gerei um exemplo mínimo e funcionou praticamente com o seu código, fiz uma alteração `enviarCadastro` que no momento da inserção e no seu retorno é identificado se o `status`retorno 201 que diz que o registro foi criado e assim usei os dados do retorno para atualizar a lista, exemplo:

```
import React, { FormEvent, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface IUser {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  company?: string;
  phone?: string;
}

function User() {
  const [usuarios, setUsuarios] = useState<IUser[]>([]);

  const inputNome = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const inputIdade = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const inputEmpresa = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const inputTelefone = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const mostraUsuarios = () => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:4000/usuarios')
      .then((resposta) => setUsuarios(resposta.data));
  };

  const deleteUsuario = (id?: number) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/usuarios/${id}`).then(() => {
      setUsuarios(usuarios.filter((x) => x.id !== id));
    });
  };

  const enviarCadastro = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const requisicao: IUser = {
      name: inputNome.current?.value,
      age: parseInt(inputIdade.current?.value || '0'),
      company: inputEmpresa.current?.value,
      phone: inputTelefone.current?.value,
    };
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:4000/usuarios', requisicao)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 201) {
          setUsuarios((state) => [...state, { ...response.data }]);
        }
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    mostraUsuarios();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" ref={inputNome} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Idade" ref={inputIdade} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Empresa" ref={inputEmpresa} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Telefone" ref={inputTelefone} />
        <button onClick={enviarCadastro}>Cadastrar</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {usuarios &&
          usuarios.map((u, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              {u.name} - {u.company} - {u.age} - {u.phone}
              <button onClick={() => deleteUsuario(u.id)}>Excluir</button>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Tudo bem Novic, deu certo sim a de cadastrar e atualizar a pagina. Só não consegui fazer na de deletar , tentei usar o mesmo que você fez em cadastrar e não deu certo.

Comment: @daniel fiz também o excluir, vale lembrar que existem várias formas de fazer isso

Comment: Obrigado Novic pela ajuda, me ajudou muito. Eu estou fazendo um outro projeto porem esse mexe com Redux, ele é meio grande, como faço para criar um pergunta aqui, não vou conseguir colocar todo o código aqui. A duvida é como atualizar o estado do Redux para ele renderizar a tela.

Comment: Crie uma outra pergunta @daniel com o mínimo possível de informação!

Comment: Blz, obrigado pela ajuda aqui.